# MTG Format Tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, magic-the-gathering

With the rampancy of MTG threads on the board & cards, should there not be tags to differentiate between the several formats?
MTG-Standard, MTG-Modern, MTG-Commander, MTG-Multiplayer, etc (There is actually one for [MTG-Modern], but none for the rest).

Seems like a lot of tags to add, and some questions simply don't need to distinguish between formats- most card clarification question for example. However there are some sticker questions where the answer would change wildly based on format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tags [mtg-modern](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-modern), [mtg-commander](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-commander), and [mtg-multiplayer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-multiplayer) all already exist, along with [mtg-drafting](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-drafting) and [mtg-cube](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-cube) for limited formats, and [mtg-two-headed-giant](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-two-headed-giant), [mtg-frontier](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-frontier), [mtg-tiny-leaders](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-tiny-leaders), and [mtg-archenemy](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-archenemy) for more niche formats. The tag [mtg-homebrew](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-homebrew) may also fit in this list, depending on how you look at it.

Other tags can be added if and when someone asks questions that need them. If someone created the [mtg-standard](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-standard) tag, for example, and added it to questions that are specifically about that format, I'm sure they would not see many objections.

Comment: One downside of mtg-standard is that standard rotates, so the questions are less likely to be relevant.

Comment: There's no rule prohibiting questions from becoming irrelevant. And that's not a reason not to have a tag like that. We already have questions about standard as a format as a whole, and about standard decks in particular.

Comment: Also keep in mind that tags are generally *not* about explaining the context of the question. If it's important that you're talking about standard, the question itself should note that. Tags are more for organization (searching, browsing, statistics, etc). So the question isn't if the answer would change wildly based on format, it's whether it's useful to be able to look at that particular slice of questions.